# SELECT multiple tables and WHERE statements

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, where-clause

here is my setup.

- **events**: date, time, user_id, business_id
- **businesses**: id, timezone, name, etc...
- **users**: id, email, name, etc...

I want my select statement WHERE to look something like this:

`events.date = $myDate`, use events.business_id to get timezone from businesses.id and `timezone = $myTimezone`, and get all info from users where `events.user_id = users.id`

**SELECT * FROM** events, businesses, users WHERE ...

Is it possible to do this in one select query? If so, how? Thanks

Comment: Exactly how you might think: `WHERE events.date = '.$myDate.' ...`

Comment: Maybe this link will help [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475850/how-can-an-sql-query-return-data-from-multiple-tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475850/how-can-an-sql-query-return-data-from-multiple-tables)

Comment: Don't use the comma separated joins, use the explicit `join` syntax with `on`s. You can filter down with a `where` and the table aliases as you make them. For example,  `from events as e join buisnesses as b on e.business_id = b.ud where b.name = 'chris cool company' and u.name = 'chris85'`.. i didnt define the `u` here but you get the picture? or you could use an `or` if you wanted my cool company, and all my other businesses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM events E
     INNER JOIN businesses B ON E.business_id = B.id
     INNER JOIN USERS U ON E.user_id= U.id
WHERE 
     E.date = $myDate
```